# convex optimization？

Tags: optimization, matrix-decomposition

I have a question about the convexity of an optimization problem and its solution. Suppose $f(X)=-tr(A^{T}XA)+tr(X)$, $A$ is any matrix with its dimension "matched" with $X$.  The optimization problem is trying to minimize $f(X)$ such that $X$ has to be a p.s.d matrix(member of a p.s.d cone). This is a convex optimization problem as the cost function is linear in $X$.

This problem can be solved in projected gradient method.  But a lot of projection on p.s.d cone has to be performed through thresholding the eigen value. The computational complexity is huge for high dimensional $X$.

I am trying to avoid projection onto p.s.d cone. First, I want to replace $X$ by $Y^{T}Y$, and the problem becomes minimize $f(Y)=-tr(A^{T}Y^{T}YA)+||Y||^{2}_{F}$ such that  $Y^{T}Y$ is a p.s.d matrix. Since  $Y^{T}Y$ must be a p.s.d matrix, the constraint is removed. The problem is not convex because of the first term$f(Y)=-tr(A^{T}Y^{T}YA)$. In this case, what kind of method should be applied to solving this problem?  Also, what will be the difference in terms of solving the problem between the case when $Y$ is full rank square matrix like $X$ and when $Y^{T}Y$ is a low rank matrix(for example $Y$ is m by n matrix and m is (much)smaller than n. Here rank(Y)<=min{m,n}?

Does what I did for the problem make sense?   For original problem, what is the best way to solve it?

Many Thanks

Henry

Comment: I suppose $A$ is a vector?

Comment: @Hans Engler   Sorry I did not make myself clear, A is a matrix and I will edit the problem. Thank you

Comment: But $A$ needs to be a column vector in order for the output of $f$ to be a scalar.

Comment: @littleO  My bad. I made the clarification. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sam Burer and co-workers attacked semi-definite programming problems using this nonlinear programming strategy some 10 years ago.

> Solving a class of semidefinite programs via nonlinear programming
>   Samuel Burer, Renato DC Monteiro, Yin Zhang. Mathematical Programming
>   Volume 93, Issue 1, Pages 97-122